Defining translations for nested forms in namespaced resources
I have the below setup
class BudgetLine < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :budget_line_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :budget_line_items
end

class BudgetLine::Accommodation < BudgetLine
end

class BudgetLineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :budget_line
end

Now I'm trying to specify labels for the nested form of BudgetLineItem inside BudgetLine::Accommodation. According to the i18n documentation, you can normally do something like this:
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user/role:
        admin: "Admin"
        contributor: "Contributor"


This works if the model in question is not namespaced, as with User above. However, when you want to specify a namespaced model it has the same syntax, so it becomes:
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      budget_line/accommodation/budget_line_items:
        unit: Room

which does not work.
I've tried different variations of this, e.g.
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      budget_line:
        accommodation/budget_line_items:
          price: Price (USD)

which also does not work, because this way of specifying namespaces in locales seems to be deprecated.
As far as I understand, for the label to be translated correctly, the following should return the correct translation: BudgetLine::Accommodation.human_attribute_name("budget_line_items.unit"), but so far I've been unsuccessful in my attempts to target this.
Is there a way to solve for this use case?

It's not depreachiated. You just have unrealistic expectations of how it's supposted to work.
Rails looks up translations through the API provived by ActiveModel::Naming which is just based on the class name:
class Foo
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
end

Foo.name                 == "foo"
Foo.model_name.i18n_key  == :foo

# This is the correct way to define nested classes
class Foo
  class Bar
    extend ActiveModel::Naming
  end
end

Foo::Bar.name     == "Foo::Bar"
Foo::Bar.i18n_key == :"foo/bar"

As you can see nested constants use / as the separator for I18n keys as : has special significance in YAML.
I don't know if you're maybe confusing constant nesting which is a language level feature with nested attributes or just somehow thinking that the associations play a role in this (they don't).
BudgetLineItem is a the top level module nesting (main) and it's I18n key is :budget_line_item no matter if it belongs_to a X or Y.
Rails is thus always going to lookup the translation from:
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      budget_line:
        price: Price (USD)

If you wanted the model to be translated differently you would use different classes with different nesting:
class BudgetLine
  class Accommodation < BudgetLine
    class BudgetLineItem < ::BudgetLineItem 
      # ...
    end
  end
end


Thanks for the feedback. And I appreciate the insight into the ActiveModel::Naming. I think my misunderstanding here relates to the wording in the documentation link I included in the original post. There it states that nested attributes can be accessed with model/attribute. I still find this confusing, but it seems like it might be referring to nesting a model inside a namespace as you explain.  However, in the same documentation they explain a different way to structure translations for namespaced models, so it's easy to misunderstand
